# angular repeat directive, run again

Tags: angularjs

```
var phoneIdentification = {
   'phoneFiled': {
        'label': 'Enter Phone',
        'regex': '[0-9]{11,12}'
    }
};

var mailIdentification = {
   'mailField': {
        'label': 'Enter Email',
        'regex': '^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$'
    },
    'passwordField': {
        'label': 'Enter Password'
    }
};
```

I have for example this two data. Default I render first one:

```
$scope.data.dataSource = phoneIdentification;
```

And Than in view:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in dataSource">
    <label>{{item.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-if="item.regex" ng-pattern="{{item.regex}}"/>
</div>
```

And I have button also, on click I changed `dataSource`, I'm setting new value from controller:

```
$scope.data.dataSource = mailIdentification;
```

View is updating but, problem is validations, It doesn't update input's Reg-exes>

How it is possible to re-render whole view?

Comment: Have you tried ng-repeat="(key, item) in data.dataSource" ?

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/9rLn4uhm/). Not sure whether this fix your problem or your code above is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `regex` property in the `passwordField` field in the `mailIdentification` object. You need it because you are accessing it in the ng-repeat directive.

Your mailIdentification object should look like this:

```
var mailIdentification = {
    ...
    'passwordField': {
        'label': 'Enter Password',
        'regex': `some regex here`
    }
};
```